# Unable to open aspx file in visual studio 2013, a blank text file is getting opened

Tags: asp.net

I am able to open aspx.cs & aspx.designer.cs and also all other aspx pages. I tried, right-click on file -> open with-> Web Forms Editor, but it also not working and gives me an error like "The file cannot be opened with the selected editor."

Answer (score 0):

right click on the  .cs file and select "Open with" and select "C# editor with encoding" and specifically tells it to open it with Western (Windows 1252) it opens just fine.